# Prevent Private Key Change - GPG

Tags: gnupg

We want to encrypt a folder using GPG, but we want to prevent a disgruntled employee from changing the private key, encrypting the folder, and then leave the company. I know you can revoke a key pair, but that's only if you know before hand that the employee is leaving.

Or is there a way to encrypt a folder with a specific public/private key pair only.

Thanks.

Comment: I think to get an answer, you should provide more information like who owns the folder, who should have access to it, whom should the keys belong to, etc...

Comment: Only a certain group should have access to the files. We would encrypt the entire folder, and preferably have a way to decrypt the data if a user encrypts with a different key.

Comment: I think the only way around this is to keep daily/hourly backups of the encrypted folder. Ultimately, it's the same risk as having a rogue user delete the folder.

Comment: You are right. I'll recommend that and see how it goes. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What platform is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not an encryption problem. It's a trust issue.

If you fear a certain employee might potentially harm your company's data, then that user can not be allowed write access to that data.

This applies primarily to **unique** data. If these are just working copies of your *master data*, then there is no real issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you want multiple keys to be used to encrypt the data, you could use LUKS volume on linux, they accept multiple "pass". Each pass can be a password or a file.
Each employee would have a "pass", would it be a file signed by his PGP key, or whatever (the PGP ensure it would have been generated by himself). The admin adds that file as a LUKS key (with **cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/mapper/decryptedVolume /path/to/passFile** ) and when the person leaves, you revoke that pass (with **cryptsetup luksDelKey <keySlot>**)

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any information about how to encrypt folders with GPG.

Assuming you are not yet committed to GPG, Truecrypt is an excellent open-source folder and drive encryption program which deals with this problem.

The [Truecrypt FAQ](http://www.truecrypt.org/faq) describes how to reset passwords if reset by non-administrators. See the question:

> We use TrueCrypt in a corporate/enterprise environment. Is there a way for an administrator to reset a volume password or pre-boot authentication password when a user forgets it (or loses a keyfile)?

Comment: Truecrypt may work, but I thought there would be something more like having two private keys for the same encrypted data.